# How to use a css file for specific pages in Symfony2?

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

I have some pages in my Symfony project that needs some specific css, in general I have a general css file for font and such, but on every page I have a table that needs different formatting.

I know I can use classes for this, but it is more convenient that I just use a different css file for these pages.

Now I am using this in my twig template file:

```
{%block stylesheets %}

{%endblock%}
```

But is there a way to include a css file? I have this in my main template file:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sign in &middot; Project</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <link href="{{asset('bundles/loginlogin/css/socproGame.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

        {%block stylesheets %}
        {%endblock%}
    </head>
```

And if I do it like this it won't work:

```
{%block stylesheets %}
     <link href="{{asset('bundles/loginlogin/css/specificPage.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Are u extending the main template?

Comment: yes i am, the head section in my post is of the main template, I extend it like this {%extends "LoginLoginBundle:Default:gameTemplate.html.twig" %}

Answer (score 6):

Your main template should look like this

```html
    {% block stylesheets %}

                {% stylesheets
                        'bundles/loginlogin/css/socproGame.css'
                %}
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
                {% endstylesheets %}

   {% endblock %}
```

And your twig which extends the main:

```html
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ parent() }}

        {% stylesheets
            'bundles/loginlogin/css/specificPage.css'
                %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}

    {% endblock %}
```